# Онлайн-трансляции через веб-камеру в реальном времени

Tags: flashvideo, php, видео, веб-программирование

Ребята, подскажите решение по онлайн трансляции через веб-камеру в реальном времени (с php). Можно ли обойтись без "видео хостинга"? За хороший совет уважуху обеспечу.

Comment: Да, вопрос этот будет актуальным всегда! Я тоже пытался отыскать решение, но так и не смог...готовыми решениями никто делиться не хочет...

Comment: У рутуба есть такая фишка, но лично не настраивал.

Comment: Или, например, smotri.com

Comment: Решение есть, поставить свой RTMP-сервер. Собственно вот и все - дальше самостоятельно читать кучу документации. А PHP тут вообще как-то не к селу ни к городу.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать свое на FLASH`е

Comment: Только вот - сервер реального времени на PHP писать крайне сурово( читай бред ).

Comment: В любом случае это RTMP ( пока преимущественно за бугром, сервер какой попадется ) + Flash/Silverlight. Аналогов без клиентского софта я не знаю. 

Не, ну а че, сервер именно как хостер страничек пусть себе с php работает, только сервера часто делают 2 - rtmp у пендосов и apache+php у нас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

снимаем изображение с камеры и ложим в место доступное из вне. А из вэба запрашиваем эту картинку. в html постоянно обновляем эту картинку через javascript. вот и всё.

Comment: какой изврат xDDD

Comment: лет 7 назад такой вариант был единственным (не считаем выделенку в США с RTMP за $300/мес на 10 потоков)

Comment: ага, а когда-то вообще компов не было...

Comment: зря вы товарища минусуете, очень интерестное решение, не требующее никаких плагинов. На работе заблокирован любой флеш контент и я был удивлен, когда на сайте увидел видео. при более подробном рассмотрении понял что подгружается оно именно таким способом.

Comment: Во первых минусовал не я, во вторых - это бред.

Comment: Ну и сколько такой способ даст кадров в сикунду? Если я не ошибаюсь это такой себе не большой ддос получится на сервере да?

Comment: Не, это реально бред...а если, например, у пользователя слабое интернет соединение? То этот процесс станет вечным.
@Arni, вы правы.

Comment: т.е. потоковое видео смотреть у него нормальный интернет, а картинки прогружать - нет.
Я не говорю, что это хороший подход, я сказал, что он интересный. Я его никогда не реализовывал, но сама идея мне показалась заслуживающей внимания...

Comment: Потоковое видео требует меньшей ширины канала, чем просмотр слайдшоу с более-менее приличным фреймрейтом. Хотя мы такое делали для просмотра камер, расставленных по перекресткам местах города — вполне себе работало (картинки, разумеется, держали не на жестком диске, а в tmpfs). Все зависит от use case: для видеоконференций такое и близко не годится, а посмотреть на слайдшоу с 0.1—0.3fps (более чем достаточно для оценки пробок) — вполне.

Answer (score 3):

Не вникал подробно в эту проблему, но статьи попадались. Не уверен, что это именно то, что надо, но может и пригодится. 1) [Плагин для использования веб-камеры](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub_id=11&id=1993), 2) [Фотоавтомат на PHP, jQuery и CSS3](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1097)

Answer (score 3):

Я реализовывал данный функционал следующим образом:

Итак, нам понадобится:

[Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html)

[Adobe Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/ru/products/flashmediaserver/)

Идея работы следующая: Flash Media Live Encoder забирает сигнал с камеры и передает его в Adobe Flash Media Server, который транслирует видео по rtmp протоколу, которое мы потом забираем любым флеш проигрывателем.

После установки софта вы сами все поймете. Интерфейс интуитивно понятный.
В Flash Media Live Encoder слева input, справа output, выбираем битрейт, connect, run.

Находим на просторах интернета флеш проигрыватель, указываем rtmp ссылку вида

> rtmp://<ip>/live/livestream

, и наслаждемся потоковым видео :) В самом Flash Media Server гдето есть исходник плеера. Смотрите в папке samples.